# C# Linq with four tables and one foreign key that isn´t always needed

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework, linq, mariadb

I have the problem that I have a MariaDB database with HeidiSQL. There are four tables and im using Linq to insert new data. One of the tables isn´t always necessary. So i marked the column with the foreign key in one of the a other tables for can be NULL. The problem is that when i create the new objects to insert into database it creates the new data in the database but the foreign key in the other table keeps emtpy.
When i undo the Null option in the column and want to insert a standardvalue instead, it throws an UpdateEntityException.
What i should mention is, that i cerated the database first in HeidiSQL and created then the code in Visual Studio with EntityFramework 5.0.
Or might the mistake caused by building and adding the database object in an if-clause?
There are some code examples of my code, i hope it will help.

```
DateTime aktuellesDatum = DateTime.Now;
        int proId = getProjectIdByProjectnumber(zeichnungen[0].Projektnummer);
        int tagId = getTagIdByTag(zeichnungen[0].Tag, zeichnungen[0].Projektnummer);
        string hauptzeichnung = "";
        int gruppeId = -1;
        //Noch kein Projekt vorhanden
        if(proId == -1)
        {
            using (DMSContext db = new DMSContext())
            {
                foreach (ZeichnungInDB zeichnungInDB in zeichnungen)
                {
                    zeichnungInDB.Volante_Index = getVolCountByDrawingNumber(zeichnungInDB.Zeichnungsnummer) + 1;
                    var zeichnung = new zeichnung()
                    {
                        Zeichnung_ID = zeichnungInDB.Dateiname + "_" + zeichnungInDB.Index + "_VOL_" + zeichnungInDB.Volante_Index + "_" + aktuellesDatum.ToShortDateString(),
                        Zeichnungsnummer = zeichnungInDB.Zeichnungsnummer,
                        Index = zeichnungInDB.Index,
                        Zeitstempel = aktuellesDatum,
                        Dateiname_Org = zeichnungInDB.Dateiname,
                        Aenderung_Ext = zeichnungInDB.Aenderung_Ext,
                        Aenderung_Int = "AE_" + zeichnungInDB.Projektnummer + "_" + aktuellesDatum.Year + "-" + aktuellesDatum.Month + "-" + aktuellesDatum.Day + " " + aktuellesDatum.Hour + ":" + aktuellesDatum.Minute,
                        Dokumententyp = zeichnungInDB.DokumentenTyp,
                        Dateiendung = zeichnungInDB.Extension,
                        Volante_Index = zeichnungInDB.Volante_Index,
                        MMS_Sachmerkmal = zeichnungInDB.Mms_Sachmerkmal,
                        Status = zeichnungInDB.Status,
                        Aenderung_Bemerkung_Txt = zeichnungInDB.Aenderung_Bemerkung_Text,
                        Einzel_Bemerkung_Txt = zeichnungInDB.Einzel_Bemerkung,
                        Ahang_Link = zeichnungInDB.Anhang_Link,
                        Einzel_Link = zeichnungInDB.Einzel_Link,
                    };

                    db.zeichnungs.Add(zeichnung);

                    if(zeichnungInDB.Baugruppe_Hauptzeichnung == true)
                    {
                        hauptzeichnung = zeichnungInDB.Zeichnungsnummer;
                    }
                }
                var projekt = new projekt()
                {
                    Projektnummer = zeichnungen[0].Projektnummer,
                };

                var tag = new tag()
                {
                    Tag1 = zeichnungen[0].Tag,
                };

                if (!hauptzeichnung.Equals(""))
                {
                    var baugruppe = new baugruppe
                    {
                        Hauptzeichnung = hauptzeichnung,
                    };
                    db.baugruppes.Add(baugruppe);
                }

                db.projekts.Add(projekt);
                db.tags.Add(tag);

                try
                {
                    db.SaveChanges();
                }
                catch (System.Data.Entity.Validation.DbEntityValidationException dbEx)
                {
                    Exception raise = dbEx;
                    foreach (var validationErrors in dbEx.EntityValidationErrors)
                    {
                        foreach (var validationError in validationErrors.ValidationErrors)
                        {
                            string message = string.Format("{0}:{1}",
                            validationErrors.Entry.Entity.ToString(),
                            validationError.ErrorMessage);
                            // raise a new exception nesting
                            // the current instance as InnerException
                            raise = new InvalidOperationException(message, raise);
                        }
                    }
                    throw raise;
                }
            }
```

This is only a short e.g. from my code because the whole cs would be to long and nobody would spend the time on so much code.

One other thing i would like to ask is. If the following code works correct for update a string in a field?

```
  private static void updateHauptzeichnung(int baugruppeId, string zeichnungsnummer)
    {
        using (var context = new DMSContext())
        {
            var query = context.baugruppes
                .Where(b => b.Baugruppe_ID == baugruppeId)
                .Select(g => new { g.Hauptzeichnung })
                .SingleOrDefault();

            if (query != null)
            {
                query.Hauptzeichnung.Replace(query.Hauptzeichnung, zeichnungsnummer);
            }

            context.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Too much noise. The core problem is (I think) *i create the new objects to insert into database it creates the new data in the database but the foreign key in the other table keeps emtpy*. I fail to see the connection with the code snippets. This calls for an [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Show us the generated SQL code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved my problem. I changed the foreignkey field from can be NULL to is necessary, added in the foreign table a costum dataset with ID is 0 and I give new data this ID as its foreign ID when they have no offical link to the foreign table. It might not be the best solution, but it fixed my problem.